# How to access folder when using mod_rewrite

Tags: regex, .htaccess, codeigniter

I'm using Codeigniter, and I wish to omit the index.php part of the urls. I managed to do this with a .htaccess like this on my webroot:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|stylesheets|scripts|css|jpg|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

and using

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

This worked, urls like subdomain.example.com/class/method work as expected.

Now I started adding stylesheet and images for my views to a folder called 'style' under my webroot. However, when I try to access those, I get error 404.
I have tried to use those in my views multiple ways:

```
<img src="/style/img.jpg">
<img src="style/img.jpg">
<img src="<?php echo base_url('/style/img.jpg');?>">
<img src="http://subdomain.example.com/style/img.jpg"> 
<img src="<?php echo base_url();?>style/img.jpg">
```

base_url() gives http://subdomain.example.com/ . Style-file's user mods are set to 755, if that's useful info. My guess is, that .htaccess is blocking these somehow. I googled it, and seems many are having similar problems, but I didn't manage to find an answer that would have helped me to use images AND omitting index.php. This is where I got with my htaccess after searching those answers, but still no luck with images:

```
#Enable mod rewrite
RewriteEngine On

#Removes access to CodeIgniter system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
#previously this would not have been possible.
#'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

#Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
#such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
#request to index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

#This last condition enables access to the images and css
#folders, and the robots.txt file
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|style|images|robots\.txt|css)

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your `.htaccess` file for removing index.php to this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|ref_doc|media|images|css|js|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

This should work

Comment: Thank you! I tried this, but did not work. No images to be seen.

Comment: Nevermind, I have accidentally saved old version of the htaccess to style folder. Deleted it, and now it works! Thank you.

Comment: @user2928505 haha.. fine :) hope you would also consider upvoting it :)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding something like this to your rewrite rules (at the end of your htaccess):

```
 RewriteRule directoryname - [L]
```

Sorry, can't test it myself right now.